# OS X Using Older Ruby Version Than Installed

Tags: ruby, macos, installation

Just installed Ruby 2.1.3 on my iMac (10.10.2) with ruby-install through Homebrew.  I've already been using ruby 2.0.0p481, but just installed Rails too and wanted to update Ruby.  As I said, ruby-install did install Ruby 2.1.3, but when I use 'ruby-v' I still get ruby 2.0.0p481.  I want to use 2.1.3 though and can't see why it's not being used after being installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew link Ruby`, which should link your Ruby from home brew with the Ruby you use on the command line.

Comment: Thought this would work, but I get an "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby"

Comment: Did you first install just Ruby through Homebrew? 'brew install ruby'

Comment: I've tried that and then 'brew link ruby,' but it didn't work.  I then tried 'brew unlink ruby && brew link ruby' as advised by Homebrew on the Terminal, but ruby -v still returned 'ruby 2.0.0 ...'

Answer (score 0):

in command line type `rvm use 2.1.3`

Comment: Doesn't do a thing as rum isn't installed and I can't seem to install it.